# Junit Ant Test report

Tags: xml, ant, junit, report

I'm using Junit with Ant to generate a test report the default junit-noframes format. 
Since I'm testing several different classes in the same package I'd like to see the statistics on the test results for each class. In addition, I'd like to separate the successfull tests in the report.

I've already examinated the xslt file, that may allows me to partially solve the first problem. Still in the xml test report generated by Junit the successfull cases are already regrouped. How can I affect this? Is it possible to change the way Junit stocks the informations in the xml testResult?
These datas concerning the individual tests must be somewhere, since I'm clearly able to see them with the Junit plugin in Eclipse.

Comment: Instead of changing how junit collect information, you may write custom reporter to parse and process xml files from junit.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough. The problem is that the xml files from junit already do a resume of the information I need, while I want them "raw".

Comment: I still do not understand the question.  It looks like RunListener could help.  http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html

Answer (score 0):

You can modify xsl file to add classname for each line. It worked for me.

In junit-noframes.xsl, add 2 lines:
1 here:

```
...
<!-- method header -->
<xsl:template name="testcase.test.header">
    <tr valign="top">
        <!-- ### THIS LINE ADDED ### -->
        <th>Class</th>
        <!----------------------------->
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th width="80%">Type</th>
        <th nowrap="nowrap">Time(s)</th>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
...
```

and here:

```
...
<xsl:template match="testcase" mode="print.test">
    <tr valign="top">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="failure | error">Error</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>

        <!-- ### THIS LINE ADDED ### -->
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@classname"/></td>
        <!----------------------------->

        <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="failure">
                <td>Failure</td>
                <td><xsl:apply-templates select="failure"/></td>
            </xsl:when>
....
```

Remember specify the folder where your modified junit-noframes.xsl file is, by setting "styledir" property (in build.xml file).

```
...
<report todir="${build.test.resultshtml.dir}"
                format="noframes" 
                styledir="${build.resources.dir}"
        />
...
```

The new column will show class name in the report

[click to see image...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/305kS.png)